# Comparing "tagName" property to "img" does not work for an <img> element

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this code snippet:

```
function switchEvent() {
    if (this.lastChild.tagName == "img" ) {
        var remove = this.lastChild;
        this.removeChild(remove);
    }
    else {
        console.log(this.lastChild);

        var image = document.createElement('img');
    }
}
```

Note, in the second part, when I check the console.log, it prints out:

```
<img height="20" width="75" src="btn2.png" style="left: -14px; right: 0px;">
```

It just skips over the 'if' and jumps to the 'else'. 
uhhh,what?

Edit: to fill you in, this is an onclick event. Therefore 'this' refers to the clicked element.

Comment: How are you calling `switchEvent`?  What does `console.log(this.lastChild.tagName)` show?  How about `console.log(this.lastChild);`?  What browser are you testing in?  What does your HTML look like?  How much debugging have you tried?

Comment: And when you debug this, what is the value of `this.lastChild.tagName` in the debugger?  I'm guessing it's *not* `"img"`.  Chances are there's an error in your assumptions, not in the JavaScript language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
if (this.lastChild.tagName == "IMG") {
// ...
```

The "tagName" property is upper-case. Or, you could not make that assumption and force the matter:

```
if (this.lastChild.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
// ...
```

should also work. However, that second version will run into problems if your last child node isn't a node with a tag name — for example, if it's a text or comment node.  You'd get an exception with that, but not for the first one.  You could make an explicit `undefined` test, but the upper-case convention is actually in the HTML DOM Level 1 spec, so it's a pretty safe assumption to make. (*edit* a smart person points out that the `.nodeName` property will always be there, and that it's the same as `.tagName` for element nodes. It's also upper-case.)

Comment: What if the `lastChild` would be a textnode?

Comment: Using `.nodeName` instead of `.tagName` will avoid the exception. All nodes have a `.nodeName`, and element nodes give the same value for it as they give for `.tagName`.

Comment: @Pointy Hmm... I was expecting `lastElementChild` ; ).

Comment: Setting aside browser support concerns (mostly IE8 at this point), @Teemu's suggestion would be the way to go.

Comment: @cookiemonster yes, if that's what supports the actual intent. I mean, if you're interested in the actual *last* node, then no, but if it's the last element without regard for other stuff, then yes. (Probably yes.)

Comment: @Pointy: Very true. I guess I shouldn't make that assumption.